# How can I turn off VisualStudio including all .cs files?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-5

VisualStudio is adding all .cs files it finds under the project folder to the project (it used to not do this - this may be due to being a .Net 5.0 app). How can I turn this functionality off?

The problem I have is running the debugger for a .Net 5.0 process in a docker container, it copies the files to a subfolder (under backtest) and I think is running that set of files. But as it's under the main project folder, those files then get added to the project.

[image]

Comment: @lostinbinary's answer is probably the one you want

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that's it - thanks